# Log into a site, and then download a file, in Swift

Tags: swift, file, download, urlsession

I'm downloading a CSV file from a website. I need to download this file while being logged in. The CSV file gives player projections for fantasy sports. When you download the file it will give you five players. However, if you purchase the premium service you get all player projections. I purchased the premium service, so, I'm trying to download this file while being signed into my account.

The code below downloads the CSV file with only five players. How do I sign into my account and then download this file?

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nba-player.csv?site=fanduel") else {  return }

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    // I don't know what I'm doing here. Also, the user name and password is not correct
    let credential = URLCredential(user: "joe", password: "12345", persistence: .forSession)
    let protectionSpace = URLProtectionSpace(host: "rotogrinders.com", port: 443, protocol: "https", realm: "Restricted", authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic)

    // I don't know what I'm doing here either.
    let credentialStorage = URLCredentialStorage()
    credentialStorage.set(credential, for: protectionSpace)

    config.urlCredentialStorage = credentialStorage

    let task = URLSession(configuration: config).dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else {        return  }
        guard let rows = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)?.components(separatedBy: "\n") else {   return  }
        print(rows)
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: you can't just expect all website services to conform to something as simplistic as you wrote above since they are probably using a middleware API layer that is a custom API with custom log in functions that are called to protect their main database and data from ppl doing exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this site doesn't have an API. They specifically don't allow the use case you are trying to do.

https://rotogrinders.com/threads/site-with-api-597932

However, there are great tools in Python that may let you do what you are trying to do. Take a look at scrapy:

https://www.edureka.co/blog/web-scraping-with-python/